# Passing Lodash's iteration item from the forEach method to a function

Tags: lodash

Considering the following simple example:

```
_.each(activeListItems, function(element){ 
   toggleActiveItem(element);
});
```

How could I pass the item from each iteration to a "external" function, like this:

```
_.each(activeListItems, doSomething(item) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close.

```
_.each(activeListItems, doSomething);

function doSomething(element, index) {
  console.log(element, index);
}
```